# Determining if Algebraic varieties are homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

So attempting to use the language of algebraic geometry, and algebraic variety $V$ is a the set of points that is the solution to some collection of algebraic relations

$$x_1, \ldots, x_n \ \text{s.t.}$$
$$ P_1(x_1, x_2 , \ldots,  x_n) = 0 \\ P_2(x_1, x_2 , \ldots,  x_n) = 0 \\ \vdots \\ P_k(x_1, x_2 , \ldots,  x_n) = 0 $$

If we restrict our attention to $\mathbb{R}^n$ as the module from which we find the vector $(x_1 , \ldots, x_n)$ a natural question arises, given two varieties $V_1, V_2$ how can we algorithmically determine if they are homeomorphic and also specifically: ambient-isotopic.

is there research in this area? what are the best known results

Comment: Do you mean isomorphic? Being homeomorphic isn't interesting for varieties. For example, any two irreducible curves (over $\mathbb{C}$) are homemorphic. For the reals, maybe just make sure they're connected or something, but the point still stands.

Comment: Over $\mathbb{R}$ it is interesting though, for example the shape $$(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} \ s.t. x^2 + y^2 = 1$$ is not homeomorphic to $$(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} \ s.t. 4x + 3y = 12$$

Comment: @Derek homeomorphism isn't interesting in the Zariski topology. Not all curves are homeomorphic with the usual topology. All compact orientable surfaces are algebraic curves.

Comment: I think any knot in $S^3$ can probably be represented by an algebraic curve in $\mathbb R^3$. So an algorithm for isotopy would let you classify knots at the very least. I would suspect that no algorithms for these things exist.

Comment: Further evidence: let's say we're working over the integers. The solution to Hilbert's tenth problem tells us there isn't even an algorithm to determine whether a variety is nonempty.

Comment: @MattSamuel ah that's going to probably make this impossible. But on the note of the question: is it impossible to talk about a Variety as a collection of "smooth shapes" in $\mathbb{R}^n$? I recalled, after you mentioned Zariski, that a shape itself can have multiple topologies on it, and I don't know if there is something called a "natural" or "default" largest topology that can be endowed to a shape.

Comment: Over the real and complex numbers we have the usual topology, which is very nice. For algebraic varieties over any ring we have the Zariski topology, which is very coarse. For ordinary geometry the usual topology is more natural. For algebraic geometry the Zariski topology gives you a better algebraic hold on the space, giving you more tools to work with. If you're studying real or complex varieties, then you often end up working with both topologies at some point.